Can't kill server running in subprocess - python
I am using the subprocess module. And using Popen to start the server subprocess.
# create a process for the server to run on
process = Popen("poetry run -vvv python ./app/server.py", cwd="./api", stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

The script posts some data on the server and when all the response are received i want to close the subprocess.
server.py starts a fastapi server with uvicorn listening on localhost:8000.
I tried using :

kill()
terminate()
send_signal(CTRL_C_EVENT)
send_signal(SIGINT)
send_signal(SIGTERM)
os.kill(process.pid, SIGINT)
os.kill(process.pid, SIGTERM)
os.kill(process.pid, SIGKILL)
process.stdin.write(b'q') + process.stdin.flush()
subprocess.call("taskkill /f /pid {pid}".format(pid=process.pid))

None of these solution worked. Everytime i need to run these commands to kill the process that is still running.
netstat -a -o -n | findstr 8000 to find the pid of the process, tasklist | findstr pid to assure that
it's a python console and taskkill /f /pid pid to kill the process.
I call this method at the end of the script. And i noticed that the pid in the error didn't match the pid i got when running the commands from last paragraph.
def kill_subprocess(subp):
    if os.name == 'nt':
        call("taskkill /T /F /PID {pid}".format(pid=subp.pid))

    elif os.name == 'posix':
        os.killpg(os.getpgid(subp.pid), signal.SIGTERM)

    if subp.wait() != 0:
        print("subprocess return code = {code}".format(code=subp.returncode))
        raise RuntimeError("subprocess {pid} still running".format(pid=subp.pid))

The comment from Muslimbek made me realize that only the poetry process was killed so i tried taskkill /F /T /PID. I got this problem, it seems like it killed all process but the subp.wait() return 1. Is this a real error or is it that the subp.wait != 0 check is wrong ?
Opération réussie: le processus de PID 17216 (processus enfant de PID 13840) a été
arrété.
Opération réussie: le processus de PID 13840 (processus enfant de PID 6976) a été
arrété.
Opération réussie: le processus de PID 6976 (processus enfant de PID 11976) a été
arrété.
Opération réussie: le processus de PID 11976 (processus enfant de PID 17132) a été
arrété.
Opération réussie: le processus de PID 17132 (processus enfant de PID 5344) a été
arrété.
Opération réussie: le processus de PID 5344 (processus enfant de PID 17904) a été
arrété.
subprocess return code = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\HEIG\TB\autograder-test.py", line 164, in <module>
    kill_subprocess(process)
  File "C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\HEIG\TB\autograder-test.py", line 123, in kill_subprocess
    raise RuntimeError("subprocess {pid} still running".format(pid=subp.pid))
RuntimeError: subprocess 5344 still running


The reason for different PIDs in your code and the one you get with bash script is that Popen.pid is the pid of poetry, not your FastAPI python interpreter.
You could try to use a process group to enable sending a signal to all the processes in the group.
Example:
import os
import signal
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("poetry run -vvv python ./app/server.py", cwd="./api", stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

# Kill all processes in the group
os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)


It seems like your answer would work for posix but killpg and setsid are not awailable on windows according to the doc. But your answer gave me the idea to try taskkill /F /T /pid i edited the post to add the error that came afterwards.

Oh, I missed the windows tag. Sorry. Hope taskkill helps.
